# My JComponent will only repaint() once I manually resize the window, how do I get it to work as it should?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, repaint

I have tried my best to read around on the topic but I cannot find/understand how to apply the answers to my piece code (and those I have applied don't work)

I have used an example from "Ivor Horton's Beginning Java 2 JDK book" and it is the first time I'm using `repaint()` but it doesn't seem to work unless I resize the window. It tries to repaint but leaves the screen blank.

Here's the code please let me know if there is something I'm doing wrong.

```
public class CurveDrawings extends JFrame{
public CurveDrawings (String title){
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pane = new CurvePane();                     //Create pane containing curves
    Container content = getContentPane();       //Get the content pane

    //Add the pane containing the curves to the content pane for the applet
    content.add(pane);

    MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
    pane.addMouseListener(handler);
    pane.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
}

//Class defining pane on which to draw
class CurvePane extends JComponent{
    public CurvePane(){
        quadCurve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(
            startQ.x, startQ.y, control.x, control.y, endQ.x, endQ.y
        );

        cubicCurve = new CubicCurve2D.Double(
            startC.x, startC.y, controlStart.x, controlStart.y,
            controlEnd.x, controlEnd.y, endC.x, endC.y
        );
    }
}

class Marker{//not needed for my problem}

class MouseHandler extends MouseInputAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(ctrlQuad.contains(e.getX(),e.getY())){
            selected = ctrlQuad;}
        else if(ctrlCubic1.contains(e.getX(),e.getY())){
            selected = ctrlCubic1;}
        else if(ctrlCubic2.contains(e.getX(),e.getY())){
            selected = ctrlCubic2;}
    }


    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){
        selected = null;
    }

    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("DRAGGED");
        if(selected != null){
            //Set the marker to current cursor position
            selected.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
            pane.validate();
            pane.repaint();
        }
    }

    Marker selected = null;
}

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;         //Get a 2D device context
    //Code to draw each component
    }



//Points for quadratic curve

//Points for cubic curve

//More unnecessary code}
```

Incase it is any help here's the 'Launcher' class for the application

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Any chance you can produce a smaller example which exhibits your problem? That may help you solve your own problem and would certainly help us when looking through your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to call

```
super.paint(g);
```

in your `paint` method in your `CurveDrawings` class to avail of the painting functionality already provided in the `JFrame` super class.

Note, the standard way of using custom painting in Swing is to use custom components that are based on `javax.swing.JComponent` that use and override `paintComponent`. This approach would leverage Swing's optimized painting model.

See: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)